# How to duplicate text every line in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to duplicate text every line in textarea

```html
<!--
first, im gonna paste my text in input like this..

<textarea id="input">
one

two






three

four


five



six


seven


(and so on...)
</textarea>

duplicating text is depend on break line..

and the result is like this..

Result:
one
one
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
three
three
four
four
four
five
five
five
five
six
six
six
seven
seven
seven
seven
-->

here is my code:
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="input" ></textarea>
<textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:100px;" placeholder="output" ></textarea>
<input id="process" type="button" value="Process!" />
```

Thank you advance

Comment: expand your question, what output you need?, what problem you are facing?

Comment: sorry im new here, my question is How to duplicate text every line in textarea

Answer (score 0):

try this, it duplicates the text in every line..

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    var invalue = $('#input').val();
    $('#output').val(invalue.replace(/^(.*)$/gm, '$1\n$1'))
})
```

Comment: Hi @Sarath thanks for the answer but the code duplicates depend on $1. I want to duplicate depends on break line. please see my example http://jsfiddle.net/8ur8aL3o/